# How to create azure relay hybrid connection programmatically?

Tags: azure, azure-relay

How to create azure relay hybrid connection **programmatically** ?

Comment: in which language would like to create an Azure Relay hybrid connection and could you share the code, and pacakages that tried to create an Azure Relay hybrid connection?

Comment: I already have Relay namespace created, I just want to create hybrid connection under relay programmatically. For now I could only create using Azure Portal. 
Better in javascript/typescript but language is not a barrier ?

Comment: refer this [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/relay/hybrid-connections/create-or-update?view=rest-relay-2021-11-01&tabs=dotnet) Hybrid Connections - Create Or Update

Answer (score 1):

The below C# code uses the Azure SDK to manage, create, and update Hybrid Connections in Azure Relay with existing [Relay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/relay/hybrid-connections/create-or-update?view=rest-relay-2021-11-01&tabs=HTTP).

- Packages used include `Azure.Identity`, `Azure.ResourceManager`, and [Azure.ResourceManager.Relay](https://i.imgur.com/jqKbPMa.png) with
  [Contributor](https://portal.azure.com/?) role in azure.

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure;
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Relay;

namespace HybridConnectionManagement
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Authenticate using Azure CLI or Managed Identity
            TokenCredential cred = new DefaultAzureCredential();

            // Create Azure Resource Manager client
            ArmClient client = new ArmClient(cred);

            // Azure resource details
            string subscriptionId = "your-subscription-id";
            string resourceGroupName = "your-resource-group-name";
            string namespaceName = "your-namespace-name of the relaywhich is created";
            string hybridConnectionName = "your-hybrid-connection-name";

            // Create resource identifier
            ResourceIdentifier relayNamespaceResourceId = RelayNamespaceResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(subscriptionId, resourceGroupName, namespaceName);

            // Get RelayNamespaceResource
            RelayNamespaceResource relayNamespace = client.GetRelayNamespaceResource(relayNamespaceResourceId);

            // Get the collection of RelayHybridConnectionResources
            RelayHybridConnectionCollection collection = relayNamespace.GetRelayHybridConnections();

            // Define hybrid connection data
            RelayHybridConnectionData data = new RelayHybridConnectionData()
            {
                IsClientAuthorizationRequired = true // Set your required properties here
            };

            try
            {
                // Invoke the operation to create or update the hybrid connection
                ArmOperation<RelayHybridConnectionResource> lro = await collection.CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, hybridConnectionName, data);
                RelayHybridConnectionResource result = lro.Value;

                // Print the ID of the created/updated hybrid connection
                Console.WriteLine($"Succeeded on id: {result.Data.Id}");
            }
            catch (RequestFailedException ex)
            {
                // Handle exceptions
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]